# setState with value of previously returned custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I couldn't find a similar question here, so here it goes:
I created a custom hook `useBudget` to fetch some data.

```
const initalState = {
    budget_amount: 0,
};

const useBudget = (resource: string, type: string) => {
    const [budgetInfo, setBudget] = useState(initalState);
    useEffect(
      () => {
          (async (resource, type) => {
              const response = await fetchBudgetInfo(resource, type);
              setBudget(response);
          })(resource, type);
    }, []);

    return [budgetInfo];
};
```

And on the component that uses that hook, I have something like this:

```
  const [budgetInfo] = useBudget(resource, type);
  const [budgetForm, setBudgetForm] = useState({ warningMsg: null, errorMsg: null, budget: budgetInfo.budget_amount });
```

The problem is: The initial state of this component does not update after the fetching. `budget` renders with `0` initially and keeps that way. If `console.log(budgetInfo)` right afterwards, the `budget` is there updated, but the state is not.

I believe that this is happening due to the asynchronicity right? But how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It's hard to say what might be wrong from the code currently in your question.

Comment: I will try to do that a bit later and post it here, but there is not much more to it. I am simply trying to have a local state based on the return of custom hook that fetches data.

Comment: The hook is ok. That it doesn't work means that it's used incorrectly. There's no evidence that fetchBudgetInfo returns correct object.

Comment: @estus, it does return the correct object. `budget` comes updated with a different value than `0` (initial value)

Comment: It's `budget_amount` and not `budget`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. `budget_amount` comes updated.

Comment: If it were, the component would be updated, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-psntrt . Please, provide MCVE as requested above. The question describes the behaviour that won't naturally happen and needs a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wiewan?file=index.js This is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I could get to a fix, however, I am not 100% that this is the best/correct approach. As far as I could get it, due to the asynchronicity, I am still reading the old state value, and a way to fix this would be to set the state inside `useEffect`. I would have:

```
  const [budgetInfo] = useBudget(resource, type);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({ budget: budgetInfo.budget_amount });

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setAppState({ budget: budgetInfo.budget_amount });
  }, [budgetInfo]);
```

But it's working now!

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wiewan?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

Effects scheduled with `useEffect` don’t block the browser from updating the screen - that's why `0` (`initialState`) is displayed on the screen. After the value is fetched, the component stays the same as there is no change in its own state (`budgetForm`).

Your solution updates component's state once `budgetInfo` is fetched hence triggering a re-render, which works but seems to be rather a workaround.

`useBudget` could be used on its own:

```
const useBudget = (resource, type) => {
  const [budgetInfo, setBudget] = useState(initalState);

  const fetchBudgetInfo = async () => {
    const response = await (new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ budget_amount: 333 })))
    setBudget(response)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBudgetInfo(resource, type)
  }, [])

  return budgetInfo
};

const App = props => {
  const { budget_amount } = useBudget('ok', 'ok')

  return (
    <h1>{budget_amount}</h1>
  );
}
```

`fetchBudgetInfo` is split out since if we make effect function async (`useEffect(async () => { ... })`), it will be implicitly returning a promise and this goes against its design - the only return value must be a function which is gonna be used for cleaning up. [Docs ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

Alternatively, consider retrieving data without a custom hook:

```js
const fetchBudgetInfo = async (resource, type) => {
  const response = await fetch(resource, type)
  return response
}

useEffect(() => {
  const response = fetchBudgetInfo(resource, type)
  setAppState((prevState) => { ...prevState, budget: response.budget_amount });
}, []);
```

Notably, we are manually merging old state with the new value, which is necessary if `appState` contains several values - that's because `useState` doesn't shallowly merge objects (as `this.setState` would) but instead completely replaces state variable. [Doc ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

On a somewhat related note, there is nothing wrong with using object to hold state, however [using multiple state variables](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables) offers few advantages - more precise naming and the ability to do individual updates.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution man. But I don't know if agree with my solution being a workaround. By using the custom hook, I don't know if there is another solution. But yeah, your approach would be another way to fetch the data.